# Where do I place the XlsxWriter file in Python?

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I downloaded XlsxWriter zip file as I cannot use pip because of organisational restrictions. I extracted the zip file. Where inside the python directory should I place the XlsxWriter folder now ?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/installing/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For most of the cases use `pip` to install Python modules. It is very easy.

Just do:

```
pip install XlsxWriter
```

And then in your script you can do the following:

```
import xlsxwriter

{...your code goes here}
```

If somehow you are not able to use pip, please follow [this](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-install-Python-packages-on-Windows-7/)

After that close and re-open your IDLE and check.

Comment: I can't download it through pip as I'm in an organizational network and they have proxies setup. That's why I downloaded the zip file. How can I do it this way ?

Comment: Please mention the OS you are using

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 with 32 bit Python.

Comment: Check the following link, follow the instructions, there shall be a setup.py. 
[link](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-install-Python-packages-on-Windows-7/)

Comment: I followed all the steps. I can the .egg file of XlsxWriter inside Python directory, but when I import XlsxWriter, it says No module named XlsxWriter

Comment: Have you set the Python path?

Comment: Yes, I have set the Python path

Comment: I am not able to check now...currently on Ubuntu. Be sure if you have closed and re-opened your IDLE.

And also the module name is `import xlsxwriter` . So dont use CAPS.